# PowerMockito mock static method which throws exception

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have some static methods to mock using Mockito + PowerMock. Everything was correct until  I tried to mock a static method which throws exception only (and do nothing else).

My test class looks like this:

top:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Secure.class, User.class, StringUtils.class})
```

body:

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Secure.class);
    Mockito.when(Secure.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(user);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(StringUtils.class);
    Mockito.when(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty("whatever")).thenReturn(true);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(User.class);
    Mockito.when(User.findById(1L)).thenReturn(user); // exception !! ;(

    boolean actualResult = service.changePassword();
```

and changePassword method is:

```
  Long id = Secure.getCurrentUser().id;

  boolean is = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty("whatever");

  User user = User.findById(1L);
  // ...
```

The first 2 static calls works fine (if i comment out 3rd), but the last one ( User.findById(long id) ) throws exception while it is called in 'Mockito.when' method. This method looks like this:

```
 public static <T extends JPABase> T findById(Object id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please annotate your JPA model with @javax.persistence.Entity annotation.");
    }
```

My question is how can i mock this method to get result as  I expect ?
Thanks for any help.

---

EDIT:

Thanks for all replies. I found a solution. I was trying to mock a method findById which was not directly in User.class but in GenericModel.class which User extends. Now everything works perfectly.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to mock an method to throw an exception or you are getting an exception when mocking a method. Furthermore the last bit about JPA doesn't seem to fit in anywhere, or at least it confused me greatly.

Comment: You're already mocking it. So it won't call real method which throws exception

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(User.class);
Mockito.when(User.findById(1L)).thenReturn(user);
```

To this:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(User.class);
PowerMockito.doReturn(user).when(User.class, "findById", Mockito.eq(1L));
```

See documentation here:

- [PowerMockitoStubber javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2/1.7.0/org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/PowerMockitoStubber.html)
- [PowerMockito Usage](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito)

Comment: The first link has expired.