# PowerMock UnfinishedStubbingException error on final class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Trying to get Mockito and PowerMock to behave, but I'm getting an `UnfinishedStubbingException` when trying to run this code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FileIOHelper.class)
public class FileIOHelperTest {

    @Test
    public void testIOExceptionOnWrite() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileIOHelper.class);
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(FileIOHelper.class);
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        FileIOHelper.write(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
    }

    @After
    public void validate() {
        Mockito.validateMockitoUsage();
    }

}
```

and this IO class

```
public final class FileIOHelper {

    public static void write(final String file, String message, final boolean appendNewLine) {
        if(checkArgs(file, message)) {
            final Path path = Paths.get(file);
            StandardOpenOption mode = StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
            if(Files.notExists(path)) {
                mode = StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW;
            }
            if(appendNewLine) {
                message += System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }
            try {
                Files.write(path, message.getBytes(), mode);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                handleException(e, "Problem writing to " + file);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkArgs(final String... args) {
        if(args != null && args.length > 0) {
            for(final String arg : args) {
                if(arg == null || arg.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static void handleException(final IOException e, final String errorMsg) {
        handleException(e, errorMsg, true);
    }

    private static void handleException(final IOException e, final String errorMsg, final boolean printStace) {
        checkArgs(errorMsg);

        System.err.println(errorMsg);
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        if(printStace) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

What I want to do is somehow trigger the `IOException` so `handleException` can be tested. Why one might ask? I'm looking at my Jacoco report and I see this:

[image: jacoco report]

I've looked at:

- [How to mock a void static method to throw exception with Powermock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483628/how-to-mock-a-void-static-method-to-throw-exception-with-powermock)
- [Powermock/mockito does not throw exception when told to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954322/powermock-mockito-does-not-throw-exception-when-told-to)
- [PowerMockito mock static method which throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520499/powermockito-mock-static-method-which-throws-exception)
- https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-stub-void-static-method-to-throw-exception
- http://www.johnmullins.co/blog/2015/02/15/beginners-guide-to-using-mockito-and-powermockito-to-unit-test-java/

and I'm still completely lost. I have no idea if I need to trigger the `IOException` or if I can somehow verify the output of `handleException` without `doThrow`. Someone, help!

Error log:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at FileIOHelperTest.testIOExceptionOnWrite(FileIOHelperTest.java:8) // doThrow line

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: **forget** about using PowerMock.

If you have to mock static methods, then build your own little wrapper class around that. Then, for testing, your wrapper can return something **you** control; and for production usage; your wrapper just calls the static method.

PowerMock looks like the solution to many problems; but rather sooner than later, it will be the cause of **much more** problems. It breaks coverage, it makes it harder to change the underlying JVM, and so on.

Seriously: if your design can only be tested with PowerMock, this is very often a clear indication that your design is **bad**. So: focus on reworking your code under test; instead of investing time into a tool like PowerMock that does more harm than good.

I have spent countless hours trying to resolve PowerMock problems; and since I started to instead write "better to test" production code ... I have written hundreds or thousands of tests without ever needing PowerMock again.

In your case: start by avoiding **static** all over the place. Basically you achieve that by (worst case) pulling little wrapper classes around the static calls you have to make. For testing, you can mock the wrapper object; and in production code, you use dependency injection to provide a (singleton/enum) wrapper object that simply makes the static call.

Comment: Aside from the opinion, I had a gut feeling that the overhead of powermock and mokito outweighed it's use. The reason why I turned to this in the first place is because I had no clue how to intentionally "cause" an `IOException`. If you can provide some indication of how to do that, then I might accept the answer. Also, I can see why using `static`, but in the context of this, I'm not sure what the alternative is. Perhaps a singleton?

Comment: I added some suggestions in the last paragraph ... (and I dont see a good way to cause an IOException to be thrown).

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, IOException is checked exception  - it should be declared with throws in the method signature. But your method FileIOHelper.write does not have such. This may be the reason of the UnsutisfiedStubbingException.
2. I do not understand, what your are trying to test: if the FileIOHelper is a mock - handleException will be never called, since it is called by the real write method, not by mocked.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to mock the class 'Files', not 'FileIOHelper'. FileIOHelper is the tested class. Second, you didn't specified which method should throw IOException. The unit test method should be as follows (supposing the tested method catches and manage the IOException):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Files.class)
public class FileIOHelperTest {

  @Test
  public void testIOExceptionOnWrite() {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
     PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(Files.class);
     Files.write("path", "message", true);
     FileIOHelper.write("path", "message", true);
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     Files.write("path", "message", true);
  }
}
```